# PYthon 3.3 - api bufferapp. Cant update

Tags: python, api, python-3.3

i want to publish an update on bufferapp.com with python.

I installed the python buffer modul: https://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-python
I managed to connect to their api with python3.

But if i use the update.publish() command it gives me the following error:

nameerror: "update" is not defined.

Im using this code:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
from colorama import Fore
from buffpy.models.update import Update
from buffpy.managers.profiles import Profiles
from buffpy.managers.updates import Updates
from buffpy.api import API
token = 'awesome_token'
api = API(client_id='client_id',
      client_secret='client_secret',
      access_token=token)
# publish now
update.publish()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ever define update?

Comment: This is problem of library buffer-python. In setup.py is missing definition of subpackages. Fix is published here https://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-python/pull/4